# Add image title to infowindow of KML-point in Python

Tags: python, infowindow, google-earth

I created a KML point with a corresponding image in an infowindow.

```
test_point = kml.newpoint(name="test_name", description = '<img src="path/latest_image.jpg" width="500" height="500" align="left"/>',coords=[(10,70,100)])
```

The image is displayed correctly but I would like to add a title and a description of the image.
Furthermore I want to change the background color of the window in which the image is displayed.
How do I insert these elements? I have tried several approaches, but I do not know the correct structure.

Thanks in advance, help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can force an image description to display in the infobox below the image by formatting it as a HTML table.

The title of infobox uses the name field of the placemark, which you can use as the title of the image.

```python
import simplekml

kml = simplekml.Kml()

test_point = kml.newpoint(name="test_name",
  description = '''<table><tr><td><img src="path/latest_image.jpg"
 width="500" height="500" align="left"/></td></tr>
 <tr><td>Image caption</table></td></tr></table>''',
  coords=[(10,70,100)]) 
  
kml.save("test.kml")
```

You can further customize the infobox by applying a [BalloonStyle](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference#balloonstyle). See [API](https://simplekml.readthedocs.io/en/latest/styles.html#balloonstyle).